# load dvc files from and to cache using python api

Tags: python, caching, version-control, dvc

At the moment i use this code to load a certain revision of my data to a pandas dataframe. Since my data are stored in an azure storage account, this always requires me to download the data for every run from the remote location.

```
data_url = dvc.api.get_url(path="data/data.csv", rev="data-v1")
data = pd.read_csv(data_url)
```

Is there a way to use the dvc api to

1. check if the file is already in the cache
2. If the file is not in the cache load it there
3. return the path to the cache file

This way I would not be dependend on a connection to azure for most of my test runs and would not create as much trafic. At https://dvc.org/doc/api-reference I did not really find the necessary functions for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dvc.api.read(path="data/data.csv", rev="data-v1")`. It will read from the cache if available and from the remote otherwise. To use it with pandas, you can do this:

```py
import dvc.api
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

contents = dvc.api.read(path="data/data.csv", rev="data-v1")
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents))
```

Comment: thanks. that looks promising. However, it does not fully do what i am looking for since it does not cache the files if they are not there. Any clue how i could achieve this?